# How to overwrite a document in Nodejs Azure Cosmos

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Need some context or guide as to how to overwrite a document in Cosmos using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos

For example, existing document is:

```
{name: 'John Smith',  age: 25, address: 'Somewhere'}
```

I want to overwrite the document such that address is removed, hence document should be:

```
{name: 'John Smith',  age: 25}
```

There is a replace method, but just update the fields you specified in the body. Other than that, there is no dedicated function to overwrite the entire document.

This is how I currently do it. Does this mean, I need to read, delete, create the document?

```
const documentToUpdate = this.cosmosClient
      .database(databaseId)
      .container(containerId)
      .item(itemId);
    const { resource } = await documentToUpdate.replace<T>(data, {
      accessCondition: {
        type: 'IfMatch',
        condition: etag,
      },
    });
```

UPDATE/ANSWER:

- I spent a 1-2 hours looking at the wrong place. It's is as simple as assigning `obj.address = undefined` and the field gets removed during `replace`. That means, prior to sending your data to `replace()`, you need to identify which fields need to be set to undefined. So, this is what the the API means about `...You may get more or less properties and it's up to your logic to enforce it...`. Hmm, they at least should put that as an example.

[image]

Comment: Please place answers as proper answers, not as edits to your question. Answers don't belong in the question itself.

Comment: @DavidMakogon sorry not quite updated with the policy. The last time I answered my own question, someone pointed out that I should not and just add the answer as edit.

Comment: Ohhhh - yeah you were given... non-ideal advice ;) - *totally* valid answering your own question! And whoever told you to edit your question to contain an answer... probably needs to re-take the tour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a 1-2 hours looking at the wrong place. It's is as simple as assigning `obj.address = undefined` and the field gets removed during replace. That means, prior to sending your data to `replace()`, you need to identify which fields need to be set to `undefined`. So, this is what the the API means about `...You may get more or less properties and it's up to your logic to enforce it....` Hmm, they at least should put that as an example.

[image]

Comment: You could have simply deleted the `address` attribute from your document object instead of setting it to `undefined` and then saved the document. Something like `delete obj["address"]`.

Comment: @GauravMantri it won't work bec address does not exist in obj. obj is the data that come from client form and it does not include address in this case. Explicity adding address while assigning it with undefined causes the document to remove it under the hood.

Comment: @GauravMantri unintentionally upvoted your comment lol. Can't seem to revoke it. Anyways, hope it's clear that delete obj['address'] won't work in this case.